# Convergence of maximum of n independent random variables to a random variable that isn't degenerate

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a question that follows from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854838/convergence-of-maximum-of-n-independent-random-variables-with-quadratic-cdf-in-a). That discussion shows that if $F(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2$ for $x \in [-1, 0)$ and $X_i$ are independent random variables with CDF $F$, then $\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i$ converges almost surely to 0 as $n\to \infty$.

The question now is whether there exists $a_n > 0$ and $b_n$ such that $b_n + a_n\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i$ converges in distribution to a random variable that isn't degenerate.

My thinking is that if such a random variable existed, then there would have to be $x_1 \neq x_2 \neq x_3$ such that $F(x_1) \neq F(x_2) \neq F(x_3)$, but I don't think there can be. Unless $a_n$ and $b_n$ were random variables.

Is this on the right track?

([This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477140/348586) seems similar but there's an additional function $h$.)

Comment: $F(x_1)\neq F(x_2)\neq F(X_3)$ for any three distinct points in $[-1,0)$!

Comment: I think $a_n=b_n=n$ gives a non-degenerate limit.

Comment: Yeah, I meant $F_X$, the CDF of the zero random variable.

Comment: If $a_n = b_n = n$, wouldn't the limit still be zero? (The expectation would get less negative as $n$  increases.)

Answer (score 0):

Take $b_n=0$ and $a_n=\sqrt{n}$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Define
$$Z_n = b_n + a_n\max_{i \in \{1, ..., n\}}\{X_i\} = \sqrt{n}\max_{i \in \{1, ..., n\}}\{X_i\}$$
Fix $x\leq 0$. Then $x/\sqrt{n}\in [-1, 0]$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and we obtain for all sufficiently large $n$:
\begin{align}
&P[Z_n\leq x]\\
&= P\left[\sqrt{n}\max_{i \in \{1, ..., n\}}\{X_i\}\leq x\right]\\
&=P\left[X_1\leq x/\sqrt{n}, X_2\leq x/\sqrt{n}, ..., X_n\leq x/\sqrt{n}\right]\\
&=\left(1-\frac{(1/2)x^2}{n}\right)^n
\end{align}
Thus, for all $x\leq 0$ we obtain:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[Z_n\leq x] = e^{-(1/2)x^2}$$
which is a valid continuous CDF.